# N-Queens problem. Returning array from functions c++

Tags: c++, arrays, return, n-queens

While trying to solve the n-queens problem in c++. I came across this error where I would get the correct answer but when returning the array pointer, I end up getting garbage numbers instead of my answer. The weird part about this is that I use recursion to solve the problem and I only get garbage numbers when the recursion gets used (even though it correctly passes through the recursion). The array is completely correct before returning it.

```
int* Successor(int board[], int n) {
    bool currentlyLegal = isLegalPosition(board, n);
    int firstZero = -1;
    int templast;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(board[i] == 0) {
            firstZero = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(currentlyLegal) {
        if(firstZero != -1) {
            for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                board[firstZero] = i;
                if(isLegalPosition(board, n) && i != lastNum) {
                    return board;
                }
            }
            lastNum = -1;
            board[firstZero - 1] = 0;
            Successor(board, n);
        } else {
            templast = board[n - 1];
            for(int i = board[n - 1]; i < n; i++) {
                board[n - 1] = i;
                if(isLegalPosition(board, n) && i != board[n-1] && i != lastNum) {
                    return board;
                }
            }
            lastNum = templast;
            board[n - 1] = 0;
            Successor(board, n);
        }
    } else {
        if(firstZero != -1) {
            if(firstZero != 0) {
                for(int i = board[firstZero - 1]; i < n; i++) {
                    board[firstZero - 1] = i;
                    if(isLegalPosition(board, n) && i != board[firstZero - 1]) {
                        return board;
                    }
                }
                lastNum = -1;
                board[firstZero - 1] = 0;
                Successor(board, n);
            } else {
                board[0] = 1;
                return board;
            }
        } else {
            templast = board[n - 1];
            for(int i = board[n - 1]; i < n; n++) {
                board[n - 1] = i;
                if(isLegalPosition(board, n) && i != board[n - 1] && i != templast) {
                    return board;
                }
            }
            lastNum = templast;
            board[n - 1] = 0;
            Successor(board, n);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive calls don't return anything. With all warnings on, you should be seeing something about "not all control paths return a value". Change your recursive calls to

```
return Successor( board, n );
```

Comment: then a question pops up in my mind. Why would he need a return value when the only thing the function can return is `board`

Comment: It doesn't, as far as I can tell. Possibly a stepping ground?